# Ajax POST sending back empty response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm having a problem with Ajax and POST, as it is not working, sending an empty response, I'm working with text (not Json) data.

Here's the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/bddAlumnoElements.php",
    data: "methodo=setLecturas,idLectura="+CurrentLecture,
    async: true,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
return false;
```

And here's the simple php code I'm using

```
if(isset($_POST['methodo'])){
    echo "blah!";       
}
```

I've also tried the php code like this

```
if(isset($_POST['methodo'])=="setLecturas"){
    $message= "blah!";      
}
```

The response alert is always blank, so I have no idea what's going on, any suggestions?

Comment: Your `data:` value isnt a query string, you do not need to specify `async` as true, that is the default value. Also any reason for using `processData:false`, `contentType:false`? Setting those to false usually means you are using something like `FormData`  object as `data:`, and it shouldnt be processed by jQuery. Read the [api reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to know what each of those options do

Comment: I did not know about the processData and contentType being FormData only, removing those actually fixed my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change here `,` to `&`

```
   data: "methodo=setLecturas&idLectura="+CurrentLecture,
```

Parameter separates by symbol `&` not by commas `,` so methodo value becomes unwanted concatination with comma.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the other reason it was not fully working.